# R: How to get data.frame column using a string variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

The below example should illustrate what the problem is.
Essentially, why can I not retrieve the step-column with the variable?
If it's possible, how would I do it?

```
> k <- data.frame(step1=c(1, 2, 3), step2=c(4, 5, 6), step3=c(7, 8, 9))
> k
  step1 step2 step3
1     1     4     7
2     2     5     8
3     3     6     9
> k$step1
[1] 1 2 3
> k$"step1"
[1] 1 2 3
> step_id <- "step1"
> k$step_id
NULL
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets:

```
> k[step_id]
  step1
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

Comment: And when a proper solution like brackets in this case doesn't exist, use substitute

Comment: why can i then not `mean(k[step_id])` which would be the purpose?

Comment: @TMOTTM because `k[step_id]` is a data.frame, and you can't use `mean()` on a data.frame. If you want to do that, use `k[[step_id]]`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
k[,c("step1")]
```

and if you want to create a new data.frame with this column

```
newdata=k[,c("step1")]
```

Comment: I believe the OP wanted to the result to be returned as a column of a data.frame which requires adding `drop=F` to your method.